# variable passed in NodeJs request.on

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code which assigns a listener to the request object and when data comes, the function is executed. My question is, how the "chunk" variable is getting its value on the function call? Is this some kind of implicit assignment to the request object? I have seen similar patterns in JS but didn't really understand how they work. Any clarification will help.

```
    request.on("data",function(chunk){
        response.write(chunk.toString().toUpperCase()) ;
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that `emits` the `"data"` event on the request object (inside of the request object) passes the chunk parameter to the event handler.  Since the request object inherits from an `eventEmitter`, the code inside the request object that wants to announce the availability of some data does something like this:

```
request.emit("data", chunk);
```

That, then causes the event handler you registered for the `"data"` event to get called with `chunk` as the argument.

This is the same as any event handler in Javascript.  The code that triggers the event sets the arguments for the event handler.  You must declare an event handler function that has arguments that match what will be passed to it which you are doing here.

This is pretty much how callback functions work in Javascript.  The system the calls the callback determines the arguments the callback will be sent.  You then declare your callback to match that and register that callback with the system that will be calling it (sometime in the future).  In this case, because it's an `EventEmitter`, you register it with `.on()`.  In other cases, you might register it some other way (like with promises, you would use `.then()` or `.catch()`).